# Use NgOnChanges to see when an @Input is changing and bind it on a template give undefined. Use set instead

Tags: angular, typescript, ngonchanges

As per title my initial situation is that I am calling with 2 way data binding a funciton in my template

***template.html***

```
{{arePresent()}}
```

This basically check if I have a @INput variable length of type string []

***component.ts***

```
@Input inputVar: string[] | undefined
.
.
arePresent():boolean {
return this.inputVar?.length > 0;
}
```

For performance issue I read that is better to use a setter or use ngOnChnages. I tried this one

**component.ts**

```
variableToBindInTemplate :boolean;
@Input inputVar: string[] | undefined 
.
.
ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges):void {
this.variableToBindInTemplate  =changes.inputVar?.currentValue?.length > 0;
```

and in my template of course I bind just the `{{variableToBindInTemplate }}`.

However the variable seems to come undefined.

Do you know how if is more convenient to use a setter or onPush change detection strategy?
If yes how can I edit my component to use a setter?

Comment: Please notice, NgOnChanges is only called if an input is set. So you should initialize the variable if the input in optional. And there is no need to access the value using changes so you can check this.inputVar

Comment: Thanks for your answer why I do not need the changes in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This code will work.

```
variableToBindInTemplate :boolean;
@Input() inputVar: string[] | undefined 

ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges):void {
this.variableToBindInTemplate = changes.inputVar?.currentValue?.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).